# Cargar vista parcial

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hola espero puedan ayudarme.

Tengo esta vista con este **script**

```
<div class="contenedor">
<div class="tabs tabs-style-tzoid">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href=""><span>Personales</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Graba tu video</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="" style="background:white;color:#7C4182;"><span>Formación</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Laboral</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Preferencias</span></a></li>
            <li><a href=""><span>Destaca tu perfil</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <section class="content-current">
            <p>Creación de información</p>
            <select id="VistaSelect" class="form-control">
                <option disabled selected>Selecciona uno por favor...</option>
                <option id="Vista" value="Secundaria">Secundaria</option>
                <option>Media</option>
            </select>
            <div id="DatosCrear">
                @if(ViewBag.Partial != null)
                {
                    <script>
                        $('#DatosCrear').load('@ViewBag.Partial');
                    </script>
                }
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Laboral")" class="btn btn-default btn-guardar">Siguiente</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#VistaSelect").change(function () {
        var Vista = $("#Vista").val();
        if (Vista) {
            $("#DatosCrear").prepend("<center style='margin-top:30px;'><span>Cargando información. Por favor, espere...</span><br/><br/><img src='https://isbi.mx/asic/Imagenes/spinblue2.gif'></center>");
            $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("DatosPost", "Formacion")',
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#DatosCrear').load('@Url.Action("ParcialCreate", "Formacion")');
                    },
                    error: function (data) { }
                });
        }
        else {
            console.log("No seleccionó nada...");
        }
    });

});
```

**Y este es el controlador**

```
public ActionResult Create(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.IdRLogin = new SelectList(db.gen_DRINLogin, "IdRLogin", "CorreoRLogin");
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult DatosPost()
    {
        return Json(JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public ActionResult ParcialCreate()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
    [HttpPost, ActionName("ParcialCreate")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IdRFormacionSecundaria,IdRLogin,EscuelaRFormacionSecundaria,FechaIngresoRFormacionSecundaria,FechaEgresoRFormacionSecundaria")] can_DRINFormacionSecundaria can_DRINFormacionSecundaria)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.can_DRINFormacionSecundaria.Add(can_DRINFormacionSecundaria);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Formacion");
        }
        ViewBag.Partial = "@Html.Partial(\"ParcialCreate\")";
        return View(can_DRINFormacionSecundaria);
    }
```

El error consiste en que si mis datos son erróneos mi vista cargue junto con la vista parcial y sus respectivos errores pero solo me muestra la vista parcial
anexo fotos

[image: Aquí se muestra con el elemento select]

[image: Aquí se muestra el resultado pero ya no muestra el elemento select]

Comment: cuando invocas al action ParcialCreate() desde $.ajax donde la pasas los datos por parametro que este espera ? el action define un parametro can_DRINFormacionSecundaria que no veo estes enviando esos datos desde $.ajax

Comment: ojo que el $('#DatosCrear').load() realiza un GET no un POST